Qual é o significado oficial/padrão do termo "continente" na língua portuguesa?
No mundo de língua inglesa, às vezes, vejo pessoas descrevendo a América do Norte, a América do Sul e uma região geográfica chamada de "Australia", que abrange mais do que a parte continental da Austrália, como massas de terra que se encaixam na categoria de "continent", porém o idioma não tem um corpo regulatório oficial. Eu consultei o Oxford English Dictionary, que é considerado, por muitos, uma autoridade no idioma, e ele disse que a palavra da língua inglesa "continent" significa "qualquer uma das principais áreas terrestres muito grandes".
Alguns artigos web até usam o termo "continente" de forma a fazer referência à Zelândia, massa de terra submersa. Eu até encontrei este artigo, que basicamente diz que a educação estadunidense tende a usar um modelo de "sete continentes". Porém, diferentemente da língua inglesa, o português tem várias academias regulatórias, e eu moro no Brasil, um importante centro de cultura lusófona. Eu sei que alguns dicionários definem o termo de uma forma o tanto quanto abrangente, mas eu queria uma definição útil e padrão.
O Cambridge English–Portuguese dictionary traduz "continent" como "continente". O dicionário bilíngue da Collins também faz isso. Porém eu não acho que isso prove que, de fato, o termo "continente" tenha oficialmente o exato mesmo significado do termo semelhante do inglês, especialmente porque o dicionário bílingue da Cambridge, por mais que seja geralmente competente, aparentemente foi escrito com o uso de consultas na Wikipédia, um recurso útil, mas imperfeito. O dicionário da Collins foi escrito com a ajuda de nativos de língua portuguesa e experts da língua inglesa, mas não acho que sua equipe editorial incluiu uma pessoa qualificada em geografia.
Alguns dicionários de língua portuguesa são de natureza descritivista. Ou seja, não são feitos para serem recursos de gramática normativa. Mesmo que alguns artigos usem o termo "continente" para descrever massas de terra que não são convencionalmente descritas como "continente" na geografia do mundo lusófono, como tenho certeza que esse uso está certo? E se esses artigos não estiverem estritamente seguindo a norma-padrão brasileira.
Se isso não estiver certo conforme a linguagem padrão do Brasil, então uma destas duas grandes preposições é provavelmente verdade:

Hipótese 1: Há dicionários que definem o termo de uma maneira que não é abrangente o suficiente, uma maneira que não considera essas teses continentais, que são válidas.
Hipótese 2: A situação é pior, porque o termo de língua inglesa não tem um equivalente semântico exato num contexto oficial lusófono.

Como eu posso saber se isso é padrão ou não no idioma tratado, conforme as academias relevantes à questão.

Existe dois problemas de lógica nesta pregunta. O fato que o verbete continente inclui ou não um número x de regióes na definição nada tem a ver com a gramática da língua em si.  Otro ponto: “o dicionário é um texto que fala da língua e da cultura, funcionando como um componente de expressão cultural e ideológica, tecido sob a aparência de catálogo de palavras” (Krieger, 2010, p. 136). Lexicografia: uma ciência interdisciplinar
Lexicography: an interdisciplinary science. Procura com google. Ótimo artigo.

Você escreveu: "Alguns dicionários de língua portuguesa são de natureza descritivista. Ou seja, não são feitos para serem recursos de gramática normativa".  Gramática em si não é alvo de um dicionário. Existe mais continuidade em verbetes como continente entre todos os dicionários da língua portuguesa do que qualquer pretendida diferença entre eles. Esse problema é cultural e não de linguagem.

A pergunta está correcta no que insinua mas não se apercebe da grande lição linguística em que se assenta. É verdade que "continente" em português não se traduza a "continent" em inglês, ainda que essa palavra seja propriamente nossa e o inglês a tenha tomado dos franceses quando por eles foram conquistados em 1066; mas do mesmo modo que sinônimos perfeitos dentro de uma língua quase inexistem, traduções perfeitas entre línguas também quase inexistem — esse facto não se limita ao lexema 'continente'.

A gramática normativa/prescritivista é o estudo da norma-padrão. Por isso, eu classifiquei o post usando a tag "gramática".

"É verdade que "continente" em português não se traduza [sic] a "continent" em inglês, ainda que essa palavra seja propriamente nossa". Falso. A continent could be a single landmass or a part of a very large landmass, as in the case of Asia or Europe. Due to this, the number of continents varies; up to seven or as few as four geographical regions are commonly regarded as continents. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continent A palavra vem do latim. terra continens.  Depende do pais e seus historiadores em matéria de geografia. É um assunto de cultura, não de língua.

Oxford English Dictionary: [not Wiktionary] continent is a borrowing from Latin.
Etymons: Latin continēnt-em. //https://www.etymonline.com/word/continent1550s, "continuous tract of land," from continent land (mid-15c.), translating Medieval Latin terra continens "continuous land," from Latin continens "continuous," present participle of continere "to hold together, enclose,"

Na língua portuguesa, os subcontinentes, às vezes, são considerados continentes. Porém, esse não é o caso na língua inglesa, em geral. [Consulte dicionários.]

Repetindo. A palavra 'continente' é nossa, é nativa da nossa língua. O inglês a emprestou do francês. A palavra 'continent' não é do latim até porque 'continent' não existe em latim, inglês nada tem a ver com latim, tem mais o que ver com o chinês, então não poderia nunca ter uma palavra latina, somente empremgas latinismos como qualquer língua do mundo pode.

Priberam:continente:  Origem etimológica:latim continens, -entis.
"continente", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2024, https://dicionario.priberam.org/continente.

A geografia é uma área intrinsecamente multidisciplinar, firmemente ancorada ao mesmo tempo nas ciências exatas e humanas. Assim, conceitos de geografia como "continente" têm como objetivo serem descritores úteis em diversos contextos, considerando critérios não apenas físicos (e.g., geológicos, climáticos), como também humanos (e.g., políticos, culturais). Dessa forma, fica difícil uniformizar completamente definições e convenções, dado que contextos diferentes pedem definições diferentes — sem mencionar que não há unanimidade entre os geógrafos (incidentalmente, o conceito relacionado de "ilha" também é alvo de discussões acadêmicas, exemplo).
"Continente" é um grande território (contíguo) delimitado (majoritariamente) por oceanos, em que "grande" por vezes é definido como "maior que a Groenlândia". Me parece que qualquer dicionário que tente oferecer uma definição muito mais restritiva que essa, corre o risco de estar incompleto. Portanto creio que a hipótese 1 está correta: alguns dicionários não são abrangentes o suficiente.
O geógrafo Álvaro Cidrais, em 2000, descarta um modelo de cinco continentes que integra a Antártida à Oceania, que já caia em desuso na época, em favor do de seis continentes, Ciberdúvidas:

Se atendermos à definição do conceito que é feita no Grande Dicionário de Língua Portuguesa, de José Pedro Machado, o continente é um espaço considerável da superfície sólida da Terra que pode percorrer-se sem passar o mar.  Nesta óptica, devemos aceitar a classificação com seis continentes, aliás, comum na maioria dos planisférios dos Atlas que consultei.
Em termos científicos, baseando-nos na Geologia e à luz da tectónica de placas, a divisão da Oceânia em dois continentes, a Austrália e ilhas associadas, por um lado, e a Antárctida, por outro, justifica-se pela separação geológica que ocorre no fundo oceânico entre estas duas «superfícies sólidas da Terra».

Modelo que é também adotado pelo Atlas Escolar do IBGE e qualificado como "tradicional" (em português e espanhol) na Enciclopédia Humanidades, se encaixando na descrição dada na Wikipédia:

A definição física em países de língua inglesa considera a divisão em sete continentes: África, América do Norte, América do Sul, Antártida, Ásia, Europa e Austrália. Esse modelo é ensinado como padrão em países como em boa parte dos países de língua inglesa. Mas, seguindo-se critérios tanto culturais como políticos, sistemas de ensino de países de outra línguas que não sejam o inglês, como países de língua latina, eslava, grego, japonês, costuma-se considerar como continentes a Europa, a Ásia, a África, a América, a Antártida e a Oceania, que é o critério adotado pela maioria dos países do globo, e como comitê olímpico internacional considera os continentes. Países como China e Índia consideram os dois modelos (6 ou 7 continentes).

Que também resume os principais modelos continentais numa tabela:



Quantidade
Continentes delimitados




Quatro continentes
América, Eurafrásia, Oceania, Antártida


Cinco continentes
América, Ásia, Europa, África, Oceania


Seis continentes
América, Ásia, Europa, África, Oceania, Antártida


Seis continentes
América do Norte, América do Sul, Eurásia, África, Oceania, Antártida


Sete continentes
América do Norte, América do Sul, Ásia, Europa, África, Oceania, Antártida



Nota: Substituí "Austrália" por "Oceania", que é o termo amplamente adotado, inclusive pelo IBGE, e que a própria Wikipedia lista (noutro verbete) como sendo o usado, entre outros, no Brasil.
Mas, como já observado na pergunta original, por mais tradicional e comum que o modelo de seis continentes seja em português, não faltam exceções, como este artigo, que se refere ao "continente sul-americano".

Todo gênero de contrassenso pode ser encontrado em artigos, ainda mais aqueles de um pesquisador só e sem citações. Certamente Jurandyr [sic] foi ensinada nas escolas que a América é um continente só mais que a Europa ou a Ásia são; o erro dela não justifica opróbrios à geografia.

@Quaestoria Cito um artigo só reconhecer a existência das exceções mencionadas pela pergunta original, embora valha notar que o autor é um pesquisador renomado. Preferiria ter estatísticas ou uma definição explícita alguma sociedade relevante, mas o melhor que consegui são os argumentos e exemplos que coloco na resposta.

Pessoalmente, não acho que seja um problema "do português". É algo cultural. E a tradução neste caso de continent só pode ser continente. O conteúdo semântico de verbete se ve culturalmente e históricamente.

@stafusa Meu comentário original se aplica tanto à postagem quanto retroativamente ao comentário-resposta. A existência de uma exceção não valida a exceção, ainda mais quando a exceção é um absurdo geográfico, categoricamente incorrecto.

Em baixo da tabela: Não existe uma forma única de fixar o número de continentes, e depende de cada área cultural determinar se duas grandes massas de terra unidas formam um ou dois continentes, e concretamente, decidir os limites entre Europa e Ásia (Eurásia) por uma parte, e América do Norte e América do Sul (América) por outra. Os principais modelos são os seguintes: [a tabela que você colocou na resposta] :)

O dicionário Priberam enumera como continentes: África, América, Antártida, Ásia ou Europa.
Já o dicionário Aulete lista os seguintes: Europa, Ásia, África, América, Oceania e Antártida.
É interessante notar que o Priberam não cita a Oceania. Contudo, nenhum dos dicionários classifica locais que não são considerados continentes como tal.

Eu faria uma pequena correção aqui: creio que o Priberam não restringe a lista à enumeração dada, mas apenas a inclui como exemplo. Pelo menos é como interpreto a definição "Grande extensão de terra contínua, como África, América, Antártida, Ásia ou Europa." (grifo meu).
